# BackgroundWorker in C# runs multiple times

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am writing a program that executes a specific task (to check for something), and when I used background workers (multiple), they execute multiple times. I only want them to execute once.

I have one button, with the following code:

```
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
    ofd.ShowDialog();
    string filename = ofd.FileName;
    SortList(filename);
```

The sort list function, sorts the file into multiple lists, that I later on will use for background workers.

```
public void SortList(string file)
        {
            string[] names = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
            int list = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (list)
                {
                    case 1:
                        l1.Add(names[i]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        l2.Add(names[i]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        l3.Add(names[i]);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        l4.Add(names[i]);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        l1.Add(names[i]);
                        list = 1;
                        break;
                }
                list++;
            }

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker3.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker4.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

There is no problem in this function, I have debugged it, and the lists are splitted as they should, no extra lines etc. The problem is the background workers doing the work multiple times.

My last function is the check one, which looks like this:

```
public void CheckList(List<string> names)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string s in names)
            {
                uu.parsePage("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)", s);
                string[] r = { uu.followers.ToString(), uu.followingcount, uu.isVerified.ToString() };
                listView1.Invoke(new Action(() => listView1.Items.Add(uu.username).SubItems.AddRange(r)));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        }
    }
```

And each background worker has a code like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CheckList(l1);
}

private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CheckList(l2);
}

private void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CheckList(l3);
}

private void backgroundWorker4_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CheckList(l4);
}
```

I've done some debugging and I can't find out why the background workers are doing the work multiple times. Is there some conflict or anything that I have done wrong? Thanks.

An example file I use:

```
danbilzerian
dailywatch
fitness
fitspo
bodyofrachael
```

That's 5 entries, and the background workers do some of the work multiple times, which ends up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Why there is an outer loop when there is an inner loop on the same list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the **CheckList** Method.

**What is the purpose of the first loop?**

You're Looping through "names" in the first loop, then looping through it in the foreach.

Since you're not using the **i** counter, it seems the first loop is useless.

**The BackgroundWorker events are not being executed more than once**, to be sure of that, just use `Console.WriteLine("BackGroundWork 1 Started");` in the DoWork Events for each one of them and check the output in the "Output" Window.

Comment: Wow. I really feel dumb after this. I have fixed the extra loop I had and apparently it works well, without background workers doing work multiple times. Thanks a lot for the heads up. Just one question, what exactly is "Output" window and where is it located?

Comment: Using Visual Studio, View > Output. You can check at msdn for more info and better explanation than i can do : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx